# What is the idiomatic way of creating instance of external interface in Kotlin JS

Tags: kotlin, idioms, kotlin-js

Example: 
In `@material-ui/core/createMuiTheme.d.ts` there are a few interfaces defined, e.g. ThemeOptions and Theme
It's possible to generate koltin bindings using `ts2kt` and it allows using `createMuiTheme` function to create `Theme` from `ThemeOptions`, but what is a correct [aka type safe] way of instantiating `ThemeOptions` which is an external interface and it doesn't have a constructor.

I created a data class that implements the interface and instantiate it. Sometimes I need to use the instance as dynamic as it allows 3rd party js code to modify it.

Is this approach any good assuming I don't want to lose type safety and use JsObject/json()/js()?

Answer (score 1):

The described way (implementing an interface by a data class) is good as well as any other way to [implement an interface](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html): by usual class, [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) and so on.

Comment: `jsObject` function is a way to go here actually unless you need extra functionality from a class that implements the interface

Comment: what is `jsObject`?

Comment: sort of type safe builder for js objects: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/blob/master/kotlin-extensions/src/main/kotlin/kotlinext/js/Helpers.kt#L3-L8

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jso<ExternalInterface> {}`.

Here's an example from the Kotlin wrappers:
https://github.com/karakum-team/kotlin-mui-showcase/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/team/karakum/components/showcases/TextFields.kt

```
TextField {
  asDynamic().InputProps = jso<InputBaseProps> {
    startAdornment = InputAdornment.create {
      position = InputAdornmentPosition.start
      +"kg"
    }
  }
}
```